# Galois group is determined by action on roots of polynomial

Tags: galois-theory, galois-extensions

This is a very simple question but I can't give a good answer to it. If we have a field $K$ and a Galois extension $L/K$ where $L=K(\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_n)$ and $\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_n$ are the roots of some separable polynomial in $K[x]$, then any automorphism of $L/K$ is uniquely determined by its action on the $\alpha_i$. I suppose it is 'clear' because any element of $L$ is formed by combining elements of $K$ and the $\alpha_i$ with field operations but this is not really rigorous enough for me. I'm sure there's a better explanation but I can't see it.

(Explanation in suggested problem didn't explain the specific point I did not understand, but I understand now.)

Comment: A vector space map is determined by the image of a basis under such a map. A field extension $L/K$ is a $K$-vector space so it makes sense that any $K$-automorphism of $L$ is determined by the image of the $\alpha_i$. This is what you are saying.

Comment: @ÍgjøgnumMeg I'm aware of that, but you seem to be implying that the $\alpha_i$ form a basis, or that they contain a basis, which I cannot explain.

Comment: @KennyLau Is the explanation really that involved? It was just stated in passing in my notes. I suppose it's mainly that I don't understand why every $x \in E$ can be expressed as a polynomial in the $\alpha_i$ like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a base field $F$ and $K/F$ is an extension, say $K = F(\alpha)$ then $K \cong F[X]/(p(X))$ where $p(X) = X^n + a_{n-1}X^{n-1} + \dots + a_1X + a_0$ is an irreducible polynomial having $\alpha$ as a root. Now in $K$ you have $\alpha^n = -(a_{n-1}\alpha^{n-1} + \dots + a_1\alpha + a_0)$ so $\lbrace 1, \alpha, \dots, \alpha^{n-1}\rbrace$ definitely span $K$ as an $F$-vector space.

If you had some non-trivial linear dependence $a_{n-1}\alpha^{n-1} + \dots + a_1\alpha + a_0 = 0$ then this would imply

$$a_{n-1}X^{n-1} + \dots + a_1X + a_0 \equiv 0 \bmod p(X)$$

so $p(X)$ divides $a_{n-1}X^{n-1} + \dots + a_1 X + a_0$. But $\deg p(X) = n < n-1$ so this can't happen unless $a_i = 0$ for all $i$, and this translates into linear independence of the $\alpha_i$ in $K$.

You can just continue this process inductively and use the tower law for field extensions to do this for any number of generators.

Alternatively, instead of continuing this process, you can note that a finite separable extension has a [primitive element](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_element_theorem).

Comment: Ah, I knew the characterisation of simple algebraic extensions but for some reason didn't see how it easily extended inductively to show that everything can be expressed in terms of the $\alpha_i$.